# Sequelize can create data but can't get data from Models

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm unable to understand what actually is wrong with my code. But I know there is a problem in how I'm implementing Promise. As `Shipment.findAll()` returns a Promise, and I'm creating a promise again for my router to consume.

Then why `createShipment` is working fine, and `getAllShipments` is not working.

**Controller for Shipment**

```
const Worker = require ('../models').Worker;
const Shipment = require ('../models').Shipment;

function createShipment (shipmentName, shipmentStatus) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        Shipment.create({name: shipmentName, status: shipmentStatus})
            .then (shipment => resolve(shipment)) 
            .catch (error => reject(error));
    });
}

function getAllShipments () {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        Shipment.findAll()
        .then(allShipments => {
            console.log(allShipments);
            return resolve(allShipments);
        })
        .catch(error => reject(error))
    })
}

module.exports = {
    createShipment,
    getAllShipments
}
```

**Shipment Router**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Shipment = require('./../../../controllers/shipment');

router.post ('/' , (req,res) => {
    Shipment.createShipment ('New Shipment', 'Pending')
        .then (shipment => {
            res.status(200).json({status: true, data: shipment, errors: null, msg: "Shipment Added Successfully"});
        })
        .catch (error => {
            res.status(200).json({status: false, data: {}, errors: error, msg: "Error Creating Shipment. Please see details in Errors Object"});
        });
});

router.get('/' , (req, res) => {
    Shipment.getAllShipments()
        .then(allShipments => {
            return res.status(200).status({status: true, data: allShipments, errors: null, msg: "All Shipments fetched successfully"});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return res.status(200).json({status: false, data: {}, errors: error, msg: "Error Fetching Shipments. Please see details in Errors Object"});
        });
})

module.exports = router;
```

What I'm doing wrong ? Because `getAllShipments` is giving my output on console but route is not sending response and just waiting and waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
Shipment.getAllShipments()
        .then(allShipments => {
            return res.status(200).status({status: true, data: allShipments, errors: null, msg: "All Shipments fetched successfully"});
        })
```

to:

```
 return res.status(200).json({status: true, data: allShipments, errors: null, msg: "All Shipments fetched successfully"});
```

Just  a typo and you wrote down a status two times instead of json

Comment: I'm embarrassed now .. :D I have spent an hour debugging this.

Comment: Actually that kind of mistakes are the hardest to notice if you code for longer time:) you can mark it as a answer if it solved problem:)

Comment: Sure. In a minute! :-)